# Scala - How to call a method on a generic subtype of a type?

Tags: scala, generics

A colleague wrote the following code:

```
  def nonEmpty[Coll[_], T](implicit ev: Coll[T] <:< TraversableOnce[T]): Coll[T] => Boolean =
      (coll: Coll[T]) => coll.nonEmpty
```

The intent being to be able to call `nonEmpty` on any subtype of `Traversable[T]`. However, this feels overly complicated. I am trying to simplify it, but with no luck so far. I tried e.g.:

```
def nonEmpty2[Coll[T] <:< TraversableOnce[T]](coll: Coll[T]): Boolean = coll.nonEmpty
```

But that is rejected with `Wrong parameter` on `Coll[T]` already. Is it just a syntactical (or series of, syntactical issues)? What is the simplest way to write that `nonEmpty` method?

Comment: First, it's `<:` in type position, not `<:<`. Second, what's wrong with `def nonEmpty2(coll: TraversableOnce[_]) = coll.nonEmpty`? It will work with any subtype (which is the whole point of inheritance).

Comment: Thanks! I like your solution.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to specify that you're dealing with a generic (higher-kinded) type that contains some other type. Just one type parameter is needed:

```
def nonEmpty2[T](coll: T)(implicit ev: T <:< TraversableOnce[_]): Boolean = coll.nonEmpty
```

Comment: Thanks. I like this solution too!

Comment: As Oleg's comment shows, actually zero type parameters are needed :) I'd only include `T` here if it was used in the return type, but it isn't.